# String.split(pattern) throws exception due to { in pattern: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, string, split

I have a String in Java. Here is the part of it that I'm concerned with `{3: {108:TR2011052300088}}`

Later on I do a split on `{3: {108:`. For some reason (I've been googling) `{` and `}` is a special character so it has to be escaped `\}` and `\{` (clearly this doesn't work -> compile time error).

Others mention this is some bug in Java regex. I'm not sure really. The exception I get is:

> `Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed counted closure near index 2 {3:{108: at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)`

Long story short, my code splits the string using `{3: {108:` as the separator and crashes on it:

```
String query="{3: {108:";
String [] messageParts = message.split(query);
```

I am aware of other ways to do it, albeit more complicated, like writing my own parser and such.

**How can I do my string split and not have it crash?**

**EDIT:**
To answer some comments:
 - Double slashes don't help: `\\{` give `\{3:\{108:MAMABEARid123}}` since 2 slashes become 1
 - Escaping with 1 slash won't compile: Invalid Escape sequence

Comment: Perhaps escaping the `}` would help? It's telling you that it's trying to interpret the brackets.

Comment: yea, but how do I escape them? `\{` doesnt work.

Comment: When you say "clearly this doesn't work" it would help if you'd say in what *way* it didn't work.

Comment: to escape use `\\}` and `\\{`

Comment: @Jon Skeet I get compile time error if I used `"\{"`

Comment: @assylias Tried that already and doesn't work. Now I have slashes in the message since \\ becomes \

Comment: @Adrian: Yes, you would, because you *also* need to escape the backslash for string literals. If you'd said that in the question, it would have been easier to answer you. **Any time you've got an error, include it in the question.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Example to escape the `{`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "{3: {108:TR2011052300088}}";
        String[] ss  = s.split("\\{3: \\{108:");
        System.out.println(ss[1]); //prints TR2011052300088}}
    }
```

Comment: it turns out I had to do a clean build of my project in order to be able to add \\{ to a String. Just FYI  I combine the pattern with the result of the split so that's escaped differently by when I print it ugh

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't really *need* regular expressions, I'd use [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/)'s [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) class.

```
private static final Splitter SPLITTER = Splitter.on("{3: {108:");

...

Iterable<String> bits = SPLITTER.split(messageParts);
```

(You can use `Iterables.toArray` to create an array from that, or `Lists.newArrayList` for a list, or whatever...)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the curly brackets and then split on colon:

`String inp = "{3: {108:TR2011052300088}}";`

`System.out.println(inp.replaceAll("[\\{\\}]", "").split(":")[2])`

Prints 'TR2011052300088'

Answer (score -2):

Use [{] ..... I've worked with Regex for Swift messages before